# How to ask users a question at login?

Tags: ssh, login, authentication

Is there a simple way to ask users a question at login?

(Assume that all logins are via ssh, and a text-only interface.)

In the simplest case, the question could have a yes/no answer, or a choice from a handful of options, but more typically, the question would have an open-ended string as an answer.

Comment: If the users are already created you could insert some sort of `read -p "question" answer` lines into their `.bash_profile`'s but that may not be practical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could append your question/answer script in `/etc/profile` (assuming you are using `bash` as your login shell for your users). [Documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files) explains when `/etc/profile` is used when `bash` is started.

Answer (score 2):

I did this for my centos machine and it seems to work:

**In the user's .bash_profile**

```
if grep -F "Name:" /home/jbutryn/answers.txt > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    :
else
    read -p "What is your name?: " name
    echo "Name: $name" >> /home/jbutryn/answers.txt
fi
```

This way if the answer already exists it wont ask again.  It looks like this:

```
[root@JBLGSMM001 ~]# su - jbutryn
Last login: Sun Aug  6 14:10:23 UTC 2017 on pts/57
What is your name?: Jesse
[jbutryn@JBLGSMM001 ~]$ cat answers.txt
Name: Jesse
[jbutryn@JBLGSMM001 ~]$ logout
[root@JBLGSMM001 ~]# su - jbutryn
Last login: Sun Aug  6 14:11:21 UTC 2017 on pts/57
[jbutryn@JBLGSMM001 ~]$
```